# FlutterFlow - Show text when button is clicked

Tags: flutterflow

I would like to show text to a Text field in FlutterFlow when a button is clicked.

Does anyone know how to do this? I cannot find any resources/help online.

Answer (score 0):

#### Summary

You can do this by using a `boolean` local page state variable. When the button is clicked, you can add an action that toggles the value of that `boolean` variable. Set your text widget to have conditional visibility based on that `boolean` variable.

#### Here is a more in-depth answer

1. Create `boolean` local page state `showText`

[image]

2. Create your button and set the action to update the page state which will toggle the value of `showText`

[image]

3. Set the conditional visibility of your text widget based on `showText`:

[image]